Convolution in $L^p$ spaces
I've found this theorem without proof on some PDE notes, but I've not been able to find the proof looking around or trying myself. I'd like to know any reference in which it is proven.
Let $p$, $q$ and $r$ be positive real numbers (possibly infinite) with $\frac1{p}+\frac1{q}=1+\frac1{r}$. Let $f$ and $g$ belong, respectively, to $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$. Then
$$f * g \in L^r(\mathbb R^n)$$ and $$ \|f * g\|_r \leq \|f \|_p \|g\|_q$$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality
